# Can I manually move labels in QGIS 3 on a WFS layer

Tags: qgis

I am trying to move a label to a different spot in a WFS layer, but it does not allow me to move it. Qgis asks me for a primary Key but after that nothing happens, and if i clikc the label again it asks me for a primary key again.

Is it not possible to manually move a label in a WFS layer?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out. It is possible to move labels but ONLY if WFS has an x and y coordinates. You have to show the layer which attribute is x and y in *data defined* compartment in Placment window.

[image]
After this turn on editing on your wfs layer, and you can move the labels.